# Month name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a build-in function in SQL Server which return my polish (or any other language) name of month by month number? Or need I write my own function?

For example

```
GetMonthName(11) => Listopad (November)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the function [Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) or datepart "month" to return a month number from date/time. Then you can use the [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) AS 'Month Name'
```

The return value depends on the language environment set by using SET LANGUAGE and by the "configure the default language" server configuration option for the login.

So as per Jacek's comment, this can be summarised as:

```
SET LANGUAGE Polish SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) AS 'Month Name'
```

If literally all you have is a month number, you would need to build a datetime variable that incorporates this month number so that you can apply the above approach. In SQL Server 2012, you can use [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx):

```
SELECT @RandomDate = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(2012, @MonthNumber, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0) 
SET LANGUAGE Polish SELECT DATENAME(month, @RandomDate) AS 'Month Name'
```

Comment: As I said above. The OP is asking for a method that they can pass a "Month Number" too.

Comment: SET LANGUAGE Polish
SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) AS 'Month Name'

Comment: @Ash, month *does* returns a month number.

Comment: @RoadWarrior i have error ..`MONTHNAME' is not a recognized built-in function name`.

Comment: @RahulChaudhari: "MonthName" is not mentioned anywhere in the above code snippets. It's "month" and "datename".